# If $\lim a_n = 0$ and $\lim b_n= m$ then $\lim (a_n b_n) = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can someone check this please? I am concerned with this line: If $b_n < m+\epsilon$, then $|b_n| < m + \epsilon$.

Prove that if $\lim a_n = 0$ and $\lim b_n = m$ then $\lim a_n b_n = 0$.

If $\lim a_n = 0$, then $|a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{m+ \epsilon}$ for all $n > N_1$

If $\lim b_n = m$, then $|b_n - m| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N_2$. Notice that this means that $m- \epsilon < b_n < m + \epsilon$. If $b_n < m+\epsilon$, then $|b_n| < m + \epsilon$.

Let $N= \max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then we have $|a_n b_n| < |a_n|( m + \epsilon) < \frac{\epsilon}{m+\epsilon} \cdot m + \epsilon < \epsilon$ as required.

$\square$

Comment: Write the complete math expressions in MathJax. Instead of writing `$\lim$($a_n$) $= 0$` you should write `$\lim (a_n) = 0$` (or even better `\lim a_n = 0`, since no parenthesis are requiered there).

Comment: Yes, this is correct. $b_n\to m$ if and only if for all $\varepsilon>0$, $|b_n-m|<\varepsilon$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can say that $b_n < m+ \epsilon$ implies that the inequality holds for $|b_n|$ however you can use the triangle inequality as follows:
\begin{align*}
|a_nb_n|\leq |a_n|(|b_n-m| + |m|) < |a_n|(\epsilon + |m|) < \frac{\epsilon}{|m|+ \epsilon} (\epsilon + |m|) = \epsilon
\end{align*}

implicitly here I am making a different choice of epsilon for your first choice of it, in particular I choose $N_1$ so that

$|a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{|m|+ \epsilon} $ instead of $|a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{m+ \epsilon}$

Comment: Thanks for your help. Okay so you arrive at the inequality using the triangle inequality which is the correct method to reach the same deduction as I did but I deduced this incorrectly, right ? I understand now!